# How is Go executable created in Docker?

Tags: docker, go

I'm pretty new to development Golang & Docker.  I'm following the instructions in the [official Golang DockerHub image](https://hub.docker.com/_/golang?tab=description).  Here's the part I'm a bit confused:

[image]

The part I really don't get is the last line of the Dockerfile:

```
CMD ["app"]
```

My question is, how is the "app" executable created in the first place?  I created a standard `hello-world.go` file and added this Docker file to a directory.  I don't get how building the Docker image would generate an executable called "app".  Can someone explain?

Comment: Your WORKDIR is set to `/go/src/app` and then you run `go install -v ./...` which runs in the WORKDIR and which produces an executable named with the same name as the directory in which it is created?

Comment: ok...so you are saying go install uses the parent directory's name when building the executable?

Comment: You can read about it on the [go command page](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies) (this links to `go build` but same rules apply for `install`). If you don't like the behavior you can use the `-o` flag to name your executable whatever you want.

Comment: You can use the `-o` flag to choose any name you like for the build result.

Comment: *"When compiling a single main package, build writes the resulting executable to an output file named after the first source file ('go build ed.go rx.go' writes 'ed' or 'ed.exe') or **the source code directory** ('go build unix/sam' writes 'sam' or 'sam.exe'). The '.exe' suffix is added when writing a Windows executable. "*

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt of the `go command`   https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_and_install_packages_and_dependencies

> Compile and install packages and dependencies
>
> Usage:
>
> go install [-i] [build flags] [packages]
>
> Install compiles and installs the packages named by the import paths.
>
> Executables are installed in the directory named by the GOBIN
>   environment variable, which defaults to $GOPATH/bin or $HOME/go/bin if
>   the GOPATH environment variable is not set. Executables in $GOROOT are
>   installed in $GOROOT/bin or $GOTOOLDIR instead of $GOBIN.
>
> When module-aware mode is disabled, other packages are installed in
>   the directory $GOPATH/pkg/$GOOS_$GOARCH. When module-aware mode is
>   enabled, other packages are built and cached but not installed.
>
> The -i flag installs the dependencies of the named packages as well.
>
> For more about the build flags, see 'go help build'. For more about
>   specifying packages, see 'go help packages'.
>
> See also: go build, go get, go clean.

This makes an executable out of your go code.